# Public data set with exciting data

Tags: dataset

I'm going to give a talk about a tool for viewing tabular datasets. I'll first give this talk at a meetup, then hopefully at a series of conferences over the next few years.

I want to demonstrate to my audience how I open a public dataset and get interesting insights about it. The tutorial I did uses the FAA dataset of wildlife strikes, which is a list of all instances where a plane hit an animal (usually birds) in the US.

The tutorial goes on to show all kinds of interesting questions that one can ask about such dataset, like "For each US state, which kind of bird gets hit by planes the most often?" or "Which birds are struck, on average, at the highest altitudes?"

While this is a cool dataset, I do feel it might make some people sad about the animal sufferring. Also, it's a bit esoteric.

**I would like to find a different public dataset that has data that's more positive and interesting. Can you help me find one?**

The data should be a simple table, like a CSV or any other similar format. I found a lot of tables at [Our World in Data](https://ourworldindata.org/) but I couldn't find one I really liked. I don't want to do joins between multiple tables, I want all the data to appear explicitly in one table rather references to IDs. I'd appreciate your suggestions.

Comment: Have you had a look at [kaggle](https://kaggle.com)?

Comment: Sure, they have a million datasets of varying qualities. Couldn't find any I liked.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it looks like a promotion of particular software.

Comment: @Valentas I removed all references to the particular software.